# Plot after applying NIntegrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics, physics

I'm trying to integrate and graph $I$ vs $b$ the following integral (eq. 24 in [this paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1674-1137/ac67fe/pdf)) in wolfram mathematica

$$ I = \int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{g_i^3 \mathcal{K}_t \mathrm{~d} r}{r^2\left|\mathcal{K}_r\right|} $$

where

$$g_i=\left(u_e^t+\left(\frac{\mathcal{K}_r}{\mathcal{K}_t}\right) u_e^r\right)^{-1}$$
$$ \mathcal{K}_t=\frac{1}{b}, \quad \frac{\mathcal{K}_r}{\mathcal{K}_t}= \pm \sqrt{B(r)\left(\frac{1}{A(r)}-\frac{b^2}{r^2}\right)} $$

```
M = 1;
A[r_] := 1 - (2 M r^2)/(g^2 + r^2)^(3/2);
B[r_] := 1/A[r];
uet = 1/A[r];
uer = -Sqrt[((1 - A[r])/(A[r] B[r]))];
kt = 1/b;
kr = kt Sqrt[B[r] (1/A[r] - b^2/r^2)];
Assuming[{(1/A[r]) (1/A[r] - b^2/r^2) > 0}, Simplify[kr]];
gi = (uet + (kr/kt) uer)^-1;
in = ((gi^3 kt)/(r^2 Abs[kr])) // Simplify 
Int[b_?NumericQ, g_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[1/(
    b r^2 (1/(1 - (2 r^2)/(g^2 + r^2)^(3/2)) - 
       Sqrt[2] Sqrt[r^2/(g^2 + r^2)^(3/2)] Sqrt[(
        1 + b^2 (-(1/r^2) + 2/(g^2 + r^2)^(3/2)))/(1 - (
          2 r^2)/(g^2 + r^2)^(3/2))^2])^3 Abs[Sqrt[(
      1 + b^2 (-(1/r^2) + 2/(g^2 + r^2)^(3/2)))/(1 - (
        2 r^2)/(g^2 + r^2)^(3/2))^2]/b]), {r, 2, 100}, 
    Method -> "LocalAdaptive", AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 4] // Quiet;
g0 = {0, .475, .75}; Plot[
 Evaluate[Int[b, #] & /@ g0 // Re], {b, 0, 20}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Green, Red}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"b", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(obs\)]\)"}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 1.2}, PlotPoints -> 10]
```

but what I get is the following graph

[image]

By increasing the PlotPoints it only takes a while but I don't get the graph I'm looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`int` is producing seemingly random numbers because `AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 4` are too small.  Increasing the values to `8` gives with no other changes.

[image]

I cannot comment on how to obtain the last figure in the question without knowing the formulas on which it is based.

Comment: Thanks for the observation!
Actually, it is assumed that performing the integration and graphing $I$ vs $b$ should be enough to obtain the last graph that I indicated in the question

Comment: In that case, I recommend that you go through your code line by line to verify that it accurately represents the equations you are trying to solve.  I did notice that `gi` is computed but not used.  Is that your intent?

Comment: You're right. Actually I missed adding the `Int` line that when executed gives me the Int argument

Comment: Where do you use `in` after defining it?

Comment: When I run ` in` I get:
` 1/(
    b r^2 (1/(1 - (2 r^2)/(g^2 + r^2)^(3/2)) - 
       Sqrt[2] Sqrt[r^2/(g^2 + r^2)^(3/2)] Sqrt[(
        1 + b^2 (-(1/r^2) + 2/(g^2 + r^2)^(3/2)))/(1 - (
          2 r^2)/(g^2 + r^2)^(3/2))^2])^3 Abs[Sqrt[(
      1 + b^2 (-(1/r^2) + 2/(g^2 + r^2)^(3/2)))/(1 - (
        2 r^2)/(g^2 + r^2)^(3/2))^2]/b])`
I put it in the `Int` argument

Comment: A cleaner approach is `Clear[Int]; Int[bt_?NumericQ, gt_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[in /. {b -> bt, g -> gt}, {r, 2, 100}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive", AccuracyGoal -> 8, PrecisionGoal -> 8]`, but either way it does not reproduce your second plot.

Comment: Although not obvious from my plot above, the curve has small spikes at approximately the locations shown in your second plot.  Use `10` for the accuracy and precision goals and plot with `Plot[Evaluate[Int[b, #] & /@ g0 // Re], {b, 4.4, 5.4}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Green, Red}, AxesLabel -> {b, Subscript[I, obs]}]

Comment: Thank you very much for your recommendations. You are right, two peaks are observed. However, the graph that I am looking for and showing in the question is not reproduced. I'm beginning to suspect that something is missing from the article or I missed something.